# Is DLR 0.9 supported by Microsoft in a production environment

Tags: dynamic-language-runtime, production-environment

I know that DLR will be released together with C# 4.0, but I don't know when that will happen. In the meantime if somebody wants to use DLR in a production environment (nothing hardware-real-time-system), should he/she consider postponing it until C# 4.0 comes out?

What I'm asking: is the existing version 0.9 supported by Microsoft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you will be using languages that rely on DLR. Right now IronPython 2.0 and above (2.6) are production ready. IronRuby is reaching 0.9 version and soon it will hit 1.0.

There is no need to wait for C# 4.0 to become available.

The hosting API to integration with DLR based languages are solid. We have been using DLR in production environment.

Answer (score 1):

If by "support" you mean Microsoft CSS (Customer Support Services) then no, DLR 0.9 is not supported. But there's pretty good community support in places like the [CodePlex DLR](http://www.codeplex.com/dlr) site and the IronPython and IronRuby mailing lists -- including support by some of the DLR developers.